# Is there a way to break a partial template rendering by a condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a partial template like this:

```
<% if @foo.nil? %>
  "Nothing"
<% else %>
  <%= @foo.name %>
  ...
  ...
<% end %>
```

If possible I want to write like this:

```
<% if @foo.nil? %>
  "Nothing"
<% # break rendering this partial %>
<% end %>

<%= @foo.name %>
...
...
```

So that I can remove unnecessary indents.
Is there way to write in a latter way?

Comment: you just don't want write your partial inside `if`? in this case you could move your `if` up to parent template, or move your partial to new one (as @spickermann has written)

Comment: No, I just wanted to know if there is a way to "break" a rendering. And according to a question that Stefan indicated there is only a bit awkward way to accomplish the function.